# Топ пользователей через ForeignKey поле модели

Tags: django

Суть: необходимо составить топ3 пользователей текущего месяца по показателю "комментарии". Для выборки по датам использую pytz.

Есть 3 связанные модели: пользователи, блоги, комментарии к блогам. Соответственно поле комментарии в моделе "пользователи" - это обычный счетчик. После добавление комента в модель "комментарии к блогам" делаю += 1, но дата, когда был сделан комент, не регистрируется.

Реально ли с таким набором данных реализовать это? Если нет, то чтобы добавить?

Модель пользователя:

```
class AuthUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', message='Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')
username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=33, validators=[alphanumeric])
email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', unique=True, max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
second_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
nickname = models.CharField(max_length=33, null=True, blank=True)
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
birthday = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False)
perm_user = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True) # 0 - user, 1 - admin
user_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_img', blank=False, null=False, default='user_img/default_img.jpg')
user_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True) # кол-во полученых лайков
user_com = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True) # кол-во комментариев
user_action = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True) # кол-во добавлений
user_blogs = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True) # кол-во тем
user_checks = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True) # кол-во созданных чеков
user_info = models.TextField(max_length=5512, null=True, blank=True)
user_vip = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False) # для донатеров

objects = AuthUserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

def get_full_name(self):
    return '%s %s %s' .format(self.last_name, self.first_name, self.second_name)

def get_short_name(self):
    return self.username

def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s %s' % (self.last_name, self.first_name, self.second_name)

class Meta():
    db_table = "Пользователи"
```

Модель блогов и коментов:

```
    class blogs(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = "Блоги,рецепты,советы"

    blogs_title = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name="Название Блога", help_text="Название Блога")
    blogs_cat = models.ForeignKey(blog_cat, verbose_name="Категория")
    blogs_user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, null=True, blank=True)
    blogs_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    blogs_date_edit = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    blogs_text = models.TextField(max_length=113000, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Текст", help_text="Текст")
    blogs_like = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="Лайки", null=True, blank=True)
    blogs_looks = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="Просмотров", null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.blogs_title

class blog_com(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = "blog_Комментарии"

    blog_com_blogs = models.ForeignKey(blogs, verbose_name="Блог")
    blog_com_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now(), verbose_name="Дата создания")
    blog_com_user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, null=True, blank=True)
    blog_com_text = models.TextField(max_length=7700, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Текст", help_text="Текст")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
top3_commenters = AuthUser.objects.all().annotate(comments_count=models.Sum(
    models.Case(
        models.When(blog_com_set__date__month=current_month, blog_com_set__date__year=current_year, then=1),
        default=0, output_field=models.IntegerField()
    )
)).order_by('comments_count')[:3]
```

Comment: попробовал, получил кучу ошибок, сейчас буду разбираться. А не могли бы Вы прокомментировать Ваш код? Т.е. обьяснить последовательно что тут происходит

Comment: В этом примере используются [выборка](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/), [агрегация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/) и [условные выражения](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/). Если в общих чертах, то queryset'у добавляется поле `comments_count`, которое содержит сумму всех выполенений условия `blog_com_set__date__month=current_month` и `blog_com_set__date__year=current_year` для обратного отношения с моделью `blog_com`, а потом сортировка по этому полю и выборка первых трёх элементов.

Comment: а что подразумевается под blog_com_set?

Comment: ORM для отношенией, в поле внешнего ключа которых не указан параметр related_name, автоматически генерирует имя <название модели>_set. Почитать можно [здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) ([на русском](http://djbook.ru/rel1.7/topics/db/queries.html#related-objects)).